# Entity Framework Core TPT inheritance - multiple commonly used tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, table-per-type

I am currently struggling with modelling the following scenario with Entity Framework Core.

I have created the following entities using the table-per-type approach to have my `Equipment` and `Event` tables refer to the same `Documents` table.

```
public class Document 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    // [...]
    public long DocumentConatiningEntityId { get; set; }
    public DocumentContainingEntity DocumentContainingEntity { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentContainingEntity 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

[Table("Events")]
public class Event : DocumentContainingEntity
{
    // [...]
}

[Table("Equipments")]
public class Equipment : DocumentContainingEntity
{
    // [...]
}
```

This works fine for only ONE common table, like in this case:

- Equipment has n documents
- Event has n documents

What would be the best way to handle it when I want my `Equipment` to refer to another table `Images`, which should also refer to another entity (e.g. `Location`)?

So:

- Event should have n documents, but not any images
- Equipment should have n documents and n images
- Location should not have any documents, but n images

What I tried is changing my base entity to something more generic like `SharedPrimaryKeyEntity`, which should provide a common primary key base for my `Locations`, `Events` and `Equipments`. Then I created interfaces which provide the navigation properties

```
public class SharedPrimaryKeyEntity 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

[Table("Events")]
public class Event 
    : SharedPrimaryKeyEntity, IDocumentEntity
{
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; } 
}

[Table("Equipments")]
public class Equipment
    : SharedPrimaryKeyEntity, IDocumentEntity, IImageEntity
{
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; } 
}

[Table("Locations")]
public class Location
    : SharedPrimaryKeyEntity, IImageEntity
{
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; } 
}

public class Document 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    // [...]
    public long SharedPrimaryKeyEntityId { get; set; }
    public SharedPrimaryKeyEntity SharedPrimaryKeyEntity { get; set; }
}

public class Image 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    // [...]
    public long SharedPrimaryKeyEntityId { get; set; }
    public SharedPrimaryKeyEntity SharedPrimaryKeyEntity { get; set; }
}

public interface IDocumentEntity 
{
    ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public interface IImageEntity 
{
    ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

But I fail to configure the foreign key relation with that approach because the base class does not know the navigation properties. And I can only refer to "SharedPrimaryKeyEntity" from my "Image"- and "Document"-Entity because otherwise i'd have to create a separate column for each referenced entity type, which I want to avoid.

Is that event possible in Entity Framework Core? Or is there any better approach to handle this case?

Comment: i think in your case it would be better if you do database-first design. what you are trying to achieve a) wont work b) absolutely unnecessary

Comment: Well okay, why is that unnecessary?